# Winter Bash 2015

Tags: discussion

[image]

[Winter Bash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) will be starting on December 14, 2015 and ending on January 3, 2016. And you know what that means?

**Hats!**

#### HATS!!

## AND MORE HATS!!!!

<sup><sup>I'm a big Winter Bash fan</sup></sup>

For those of you who aren't familiar with Winter Bash, just remember that it is a great thing. You get hats, which are kinda of like temporary badges, but *so* much better. You get to wear them on your profile as little decorations :D

Here's a few examples of what hats may look like:

[image: anongoodnurse from 2014 Winter Bash]

[image: Air from 2014 Winter Bash]

[image: Mat's Mug from 2014 Winter Bash]

Some hats are not secret and can be earned by doing things like visiting the site on a certain day, talking in chat within 10 minutes of New's Year UTC, or posting from the mobile app on Christmas.

Other hats are secret and are triggered by events such as voting up already well-received posts, editing certain parts of your profile, and even guessing what triggers a secret hat.

Right now, we are planning on participating in Winter Bash. If you object and think that the site should not do Winter Bash this year, please feel free to post an answer letting us know why and maybe we will reconsider. If it is just a personal preference to not participate, you can also click the "I hate hats" button which will be in the footer of the [Winter Bash 2015 page](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) when the event starts.

If you want to learn more, you might want to check out the [Winter Bash 2014 Recap](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/).

Hope you all are as excited for Winter Bash as the moderators are!

Comment: For sure those Hat nazi are unable to sleep by now.